# read json array data from ajax response

Tags: json, ajax

Read json data value.
 Getting the following result(json encoded)

```
    [{"client_id":1,"client_first_name":"Pooja"}]null

    how can i read "client_first_name" value. 
        $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {id: clientid},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: webURL + "/invoice/clientdetail/",
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        var res = json_encode(data);

                    }
            });

 how can i read "client_first_name" value
```

*data- getting json array, how can i read particular value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your "res" jSON looks something like this:

```
{"client_first_name":"value"}
```

You are reading the value in this way:

```
res[0]['client_first_name']
```

Please reffer to:

[how to get data to javascript from php using json_encode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229027/how-to-get-data-to-javascript-from-php-using-json-encode)

Comment: Thanks a lot save my day

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get client first name

```
res[0]['client_first_name']
```